# How to populate a CardView from only values of currently logged in user using Firebase in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

My project structure is as follows:
Any user can register on Firebase. Under each registered user there is a child called 'transactions'
So the user can post (push) multiple posts under this child. Each post under this child has a unique id, following another child called 'trans'. So my Database seems like: ../Users/transactions/someid/trans.
Check picture uploaded

[image: here]

Straight to my problem: I want to fetch all the data under this child (transactions) and this data should only be for the current user who is currently logged in.

What I have tried so far as a newbie is not making any sense, and it looks as follows:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
refTransactions = mDatabase.child("transactions"); //points to Users/transactions
refTrans = refTransactions.child("trans"); //points to Users/transactions/trans
```

then

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        auth.addAuthStateListener(authListener);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Loading...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AllUsers, MainActivity.BlogzoneViewHolder> FBRA = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AllUsers, MainActivity.BlogzoneViewHolder>(
                AllUsers.class,
                R.layout.trans_items,
                MainActivity.BlogzoneViewHolder.class,
                refTrans

        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(BlogzoneViewHolder blogzoneViewHolder, AllUsers allUsers, int i) {
                final String post_key = getRef(i).getKey().toString();
                blogzoneViewHolder.setTrans(allUsers.getTrans());

                blogzoneViewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(FBRA);
    }

    public static class BlogzoneViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View mView;

        public BlogzoneViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setTrans(String trans) {
            TextView ama = mView.findViewById(R.id.trans_tr);
            ama.setText(trans);;
        }
    }
```

With the above code I am trying to populate the cardview, all the transactions of the user who is currently logged in. With the above code, I know it is totally wrong and it is even crashing my app when loading the data. So my question is, how best can I fetch the transactions to a cardview list...?

AllUsers.class structure:

```
public class AllUsers{

    private String transactions;

    public AllUsers(String date, String transactions ) {
        this.transactions = transactions;
    }

    public AllUsers() {
    }

    public void setTransactions(String transactions) {
        this.transactions = transactions;
    }


    //Strings

    public String getTransactions() {return transactions;}

}
```

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: Please include your LogCat of the error that is crashing your app.  Additionally, provide the code that is in allUsers.getTrans() - so far as i can see you're not actually using your dbRef in any of the code included in this question

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is in these lines:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
refTransactions = mDatabase.child("transactions"); //points to Users/transactions
refTrans = refTransactions.child("trans"); //points to Users/transactions/trans
```

There is no node `Users/transactions/trans` in your JSON, so this is a reference to a non-existing node. Instead what you have is `Users/$uid/transactions/$pushid/trans` and your code will have to take those two dynamic levels into account.

The first one is relatively straightforward as you want to show the transactions for the current user. So we can determine the UID of the current user, and build the reference to just their transactions with:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
  String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
  refTransactions = mDatabase.child(uid).child("transactions");
}
```

Now we have a reference point to the user's transaction, which we can pass to the FirebaseUI adapter.

---

The adapter will then create a view holder for each child node under `refTransactions` and invoke your `populateViewHolder` with the `AllUsers.class` object for that item.

We still need to cater for the `trans` node of each child however, which we'll need to do in our Java class. The simplest class that matches your JSON is:

```
public class TransClass {
  public String trans;
}
```

So this class matches the child nodes/properties under each child of `transaction`.

You can pass this to the builder for the adapter, and then populate the data from `TransClass` in its `populateViewHolder` method:

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AllUsers, MainActivity.BlogzoneViewHolder> FBRA = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AllUsers, MainActivity.BlogzoneViewHolder>(
        TransClass.class,
        R.layout.trans_items,
        MainActivity.BlogzoneViewHolder.class,
        refTransactions
) {
    ...
```

Comment: I am a little bit confussed with your code, you have suggested another class ie. TransClass, and we still have this class again AllUsers, would you please put this code in one code so that I understand it, or simply copy and paste to my code. Because these seperate parts I am failing to combine them

Comment: You didn't share your `AllUsers` so I instead showed the minimal class to match the child nodes of your `transactions` node. Since you only want to show the transactions of the current user, no other classes are needed.

Comment: check I have added AllUsers class, its just I named it AllUsers but it shows only transactions for current user. If possible helpme with the code combined than in pieces I am failing to combine, um newbie

Comment: This does not matching your JSON: `private String transactions;`. There is no **string** `transactions` in your JSON. It is a submode. Did you try my code?

Comment: "its crashing" is hard to help with. What's the exact error message and stack trace that you get?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Oh yes, indeed. As long as no other constructor is present, the no-argument constructor is automatically added by the compiler. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: No worries whatsoever, just wanted to be explicit about why I rolled it back.